How to conditionally use the 'default' color in MAUI?
I'm looking for a way to get the default color in MAUI so that I can respect system themes/etc. I have a field that I want to change color under certain conditions, but remain the "default" color, platform-independent, if not. I'm currently using the .NET MAUI MVVM Toolkit, so I have a converter defined as follows:
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <x:Double x:Key="Threshold">0</x:Double>
        <Color x:Key="FalseColor">DarkRed</Color>
        <!--What goes in here?-->
        <Color x:Key="TrueColor"></Color>
        <toolkit:CompareConverter x:Key="isAboveThresholdConverter" 
                ComparisonOperator="Greater"
                ComparingValue="{StaticResource Key=Threshold}"
                TrueObject="{StaticResource TrueColor}"
                FalseObject="{StaticResource FalseColor}"/>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

which is used here:
    <Label Text="{Binding RunningTotal}" TextColor="{Binding RunningTotal, Converter={StaticResource isAboveThresholdConverter}}"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"/>

How do I get this to be DarkRed if the condition is false, but set the text color to whatever the system default color for text is if true?
I have tried:

Leaving the TrueColor empty, as show in the example above
Writing null for TrueColor in XAML
Writing Default for TrueColor in XAML
Searching MAUI docs for a Color.Default field (I am unsure such a field exists, though apparently it did in WinUI3, and there's some workaround work that was done but I do not understand the specific commit history)

I would like to avoid:

Hardcoding Black and White as colors in the theme, since I'm only reasonably sure that those are the correct colors for text in the respective light/dark modes across all platforms and I want to do as little custom color work as possible.
Coding an individual color per platform (see How can I use Windows/Android accent color in .NET Maui? for an example of how to get the accent color for specifically Windows, with an Android solution in the commments)

Is there a way to respect system default color regardless of platform, or am I out of luck?

Coding an individual color per platform (see How can I use Windows/Android accent color in .NET Maui? for an example of how to get the accent color for specifically Windows, with an Android solution in the commments) - I hope you are aware this is not the system Color that you get here but the Color set in the theme that you have for your MAUI app which is either the default that the MAUI team has created or the custom theme you created (if you have) per platform

Hardcoding Black and White as colors in the theme, since I'm only reasonably sure that those are the correct colors for text in the respective light/dark modes across all platforms and I want to do as little custom color work as possible. As far as I know you don't get a default color for each theme from the Platform, even in the platform there are conditional themes that are created behind the scenes that update this color for you, but its not "Platform default"

These are both useful to know, and I'm glad I've found a real solution rather than either of these, since it sounds like neither would work the way I want

Your question was actually a bit vague, all you wanted was a default theme, instead your question sounded as if you wanted the system default from each os to be available to you

To get a default color, I suppose you can put a default label in the resource dictionary, e.g.
<Label x:Key="DefaultLabel"/>

Then you can refer to its color via {Binding TextColor, Source={StaticResource DefaultLabel}}
Also, you can use MultiMathExpressionConverter in a DataTrigger as follows:
<!-- Pseudo code - may contain syntax errors, default TrueColor is inferred -->
<Label Text="{Binding RunningTotal}" >
    <Label.Triggers>
         <DataTrigger TargetType="Label"
                      Binding="{MultiBinding {Binding RunningTotal},
                                             {Binding Source={StaticResource Threshold}},
                                             Converter={StaticResource MultiMathExpressionConverter},
                                             ConverterParameter='sign(x - x1)'}"
                      Value="-1">
             <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource FalseColor}" />
         </DataTrigger>
    </Label.Triggers>
</Label>

I have a MultiMathExpressionConverter enhancement to support boolean and comparison operators. It would help me a lot if you vote on the issue and the corresponding PR:

Proposal Issue: https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/issues/2181
Proposal PR https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/pull/2182

With this enhancement the solution to your problem would simplify to:
<Label Text="{Binding RunningTotal}"
       TextColor="{MultiBinding {Binding RunningTotal},
                                {Binding Source={StaticResource Threshold}},
                                {Binding TextColor, Source={StaticResource DefaultLabel}},
                                {Binding Source={StaticResource FalseColor}},
                                Converter={StaticResource MultiMathExpressionConverter},
                                ConverterParameter='x &gt; x1 ? x2 : x3'}" />


I want this. I am considering "borrowing" your class even before gets implemented in the platform. Can I use something else than "&gt" in the expression? (Like "GreatherThen" text or something)

@H.A.H. right now, I'm afraid > in XAML needs to be &gt; because it is XAML. I deliberately didn't bloat the grammar since I was worried that the PR was less likely to get merged if it deviated too much from C# math. If you wish to try, you're welcome to pull and build my branch.

Still very useful. I often make multiple data triggers on the same value, modifying single property. Surprisingly enough - it is exactly the text color in most cases. I do not mind writing ">" when it can remove 2/3 of my XAML code.

The DefaultLabel workaround is perfect, tysm!
